# Confidence interval and standard deviation

Tags: statistics, finance, confidence-interval

I'm currently talking an intermediate course in finance where we want to calculate Value-at-Risk for portfolios and bonds. To use this VaR formula I need to know the standard deviation for different confidence intervals. Now my teacher have put up the following standard deviation for different confidence intervals:

C.I 90 = +/- 1,64 S.d

C.I 95 = +/- 1,96 S.d

C.I 98 = +/- 2,33 S.d

C.I 99,9 = +/- 3,09 S.d

When I watched an old exam for calculating VaR, the C.I was 99% and the student wrote that the S.d was equal to 2,33. How is this possible? (P:s the student got an A on this exam).

Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Do you mean the standard deviation, or the coefficient of the standard deviation chosen from the normal distribution table? In the latter case (which I think is what you mean), one way that could happen is if you intended a "one-sided CI", i.e. a range of values of $\mu_0$ such that you would accept the null hypothesis $\mu \geq \mu_0$ or $\mu \leq \mu_0$. For a 99% significance one-sided CI you would use $z_{0.01}$, which is the same as you would use for a 98% significance two-sided CI. (Note that one-sided CIs are not nearly as common as two-sided CIs.)

Comment: It's also possible that this particular solution was just wrong.

Comment: It is indeed true that $\Pr(|Z|\le 2.33)\approx 0.98$. The corresponding figure for $0.99$ is about $2.575$. But one may also be interested in one-tailed estimates. We have $\Pr(Z\le 2.33)\approx 0.99$.

Comment: Having a look at this standard table (http://math.arizona.edu/~rsims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf) of the normal distribution probability. You find that, for $Z \sim N(0,1)$, $
P(Z\le 2.33)\approx0.9901
$

Comment: Thank you all for the quick answers. And I wasn't clear enough, in my case we are only interested in one sided C.I, the one to the left of the mean (with negative sign).  And @OlivierOloa thank you so much for the z table, I'm starting to get a grip of how to use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. Have a look at this standard [table](http://math.arizona.edu/~rsims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf) of the normal distribution probability. You find that, for $Z \sim N(0,1)$,
$$
P(-\infty<Z\le 2.33)\approx0.9901
$$
this comes from a numerical evaluation of 
$$
\Phi(2.33)\; = \;\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{2.33} e^{-t^2/2} \, dt\approx \color{blue}{0.99009692444083574978997\cdots}
$$ (see also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)).